# Does jQuery fadeIn() automatically check if element is visible? | Coding Efficiency

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, performance

I have jQuery loading data for my web app. Being a web app, all my code is being compiled into one file. It's reused often. Filesize and inefficiencies could seriously slow down my website performance and load time.

My question is: Does jQuery have built-in handlers for redundancies?
My example concerns the .fadeIn() function. I don't want $('.search-output') to "fade in" every single time a key is pressed, however, I don't want to add unneeded code that jQuery already handles on its own.

I'm assuming that jQuery does handle these redundancies on its own because no animation is present when running this without my 'if visible' statement. Still, it might run other code that slows down my web app. Is it better/efficient coding practice to code in my own handlers for everything or to let jQuery handle it on its own?

I know I could look at the jQuery code but you guys might have more valuable input than just a yes or a no.

```
  $this.find('.search-input input').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output').fadeOut(150)
    } else {
      if (!$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output').fadeIn(150)
      }
      formData.append('request', 'req_search_users')
      formData.append('searchString', $(this).val())
      xhr_request(formData, open)
      function open($status, $_rtn) {
        if ($status == 200) {
          $output = $this.find('.search-output')
          $_rtn = $_rtn.split('|,')
          if (parseInt($_rtn[0]) > 0) {
            $output.append($_rtn[1]).ready(function() {
              link_user_click($(this))
            })
          }
          if (parseInt($_rtn[0]) < 3) {
            $this.addClass('eof')
            $this.find('.auto-loader').hide();
          }
        } else {
          console.log('XHR POST: 404 Error')
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

This is the specific section of code we are looking at:

```
      if (!$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output').fadeIn(150)
      }
```

This is my first stack-overflow post. Thanks for any input you can provide!

Comment: I've found jQuery is anything BUT efficient - jQuery is designed to run without change on old and new browsers, and is therefore measurably slow anyway - having said that, your code is going to potentially execute `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output')` twice in many cases (i.e. if the condition is met) - which is inefficient anyway - if jQuery handles the visibility test already, then don't do it

Comment: Thanks! I want to make the switch to pure JS but right now 90% of my site runs on jquery and I don't know pure js intuitively yet. I'm on a time crunch, else I'd invest more time on converting everything over. What if you assign $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.search-output') to a variable and call the variable twice?

Comment: sure, that's better - but you don't need to check visibility at all - I'm guessing, internally jQuery does the same as `.is(':visible')` anyway, so your `if` is redundant and possibly less efficient - though, such inefficiency is not going to be noticeable to end users

Comment: By the way, first thing to rewrite is any use of `$.each` ... seriously, when we  changed all ours to a forEach or for loop, the site responsiveness was so much improved, we thought we must've done something wrong, there's no way our site could be that much more responsive

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. jQuery does apply *fade-in* animation to all visible elements (elements with the CSS property `display` not equal to `hidden`). All jQuery methods which animates visibility are an "extension" of the `<collection>.toggle()` method, which automatically switches between `hidden` and `inline` states, see https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: `does apply fade-in animation to all visible elements` you mean NOT visible? why would you fade in a visible element, if it's already visible - which is the crux of the OP's question